# Error handling when user inputs a word rather than an integer

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
print("You will be entering grades. If you wish to exit, please type 'exit'.")

while True:    #infinite loop
    number = input("Enter a grade:")
 

    try:   
        number = float(number)  # we are asking the use the same thing, rounding it to the nearest decimal point
        if number > 100 or number < 0:
            print("Invalid grade")
        elif number >= 80 and number <= 100:
            print("You got an A")
        elif number >= 70 and number < 80:
            print("You got a B")
        elif number >= 60 and number < 70:
            print("You got a C")
        elif number >= 50 and number < 60:
            print("You got a D")
        elif 0 <= number < 50:
            print("You got an F")
    except:
        if number.strip() == "":
            print("you did not enter anyhting, try again ")
        
        if number.lower() == 'exit':    #turns it to lower case 
            print("Exiting...")
            break  #exits the program 

print("Done")
```

i am trying to add something where if the user inputs a word except exit, it says please enter an integer.

i tried is not digit. function but when i enter exit as a user input it skips it, any help?

Comment: Tip: The statements like this: `number >= 80 and number <= 100` can be simplified to `80 <= number <= 100`

Answer (score 0):

You can add another condition to your try block to check if the input is a digit. If it's not a digit and not "exit," then you can print the message asking them to enter an integer.

```
print("You will be entering grades. If you wish to exit, please type 'exit'.")

while True:    # infinite loop
    number = input("Enter a grade:")

try:
    if not number.strip():  # Check if the input is empty or consists of whitespace only
        print("You did not enter anything, try again.")
        continue  # continue the loop to ask for input again
    
    if number.lower() == 'exit':
        print("Exiting...")
        break  # exits the program

    number = float(number)  # we are asking the user the same thing, rounding it to the nearest decimal point
    if number > 100 or number < 0:
        print("Invalid grade")
    elif number >= 80 and number <= 100:
        print("You got an A")
    elif number >= 70 and number < 80:
        print("You got a B")
    elif number >= 60 and number < 70:
        print("You got a C")
    elif number >= 50 and number < 60:
        print("You got a D")
    elif 0 <= number < 50:
        print("You got an F")
    elif int(number) != number:  # Check if the input is a decimal number
        print("Please enter an integer.")  # Prompt the user to enter an integer if the input is a decimal number
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a valid number or 'exit'.")  # Prompt the user to enter a valid number or 'exit' if the conversion to float fails

print("Done")
```

Output:

```
You will be entering grades. If you wish to exit, please type 'exit'.
Enter a grade:85
You got an A
Enter a grade:34
You got an F
Enter a grade:test
Please enter an integer.
Enter a grade:ty
Please enter an integer.
Enter a grade:exit
Exiting...
Done
```

Comment: when i input a decimal, it gives me "please enter an integer", when i enter a negative number it gives me "please give me an integer" instead of "invalid grade" when i enter a space, i get "please enter an integer " instead of "you did not input anything"

Comment: @SultanAlsamman, you can refine the conditions within the try block to handle different types of invalid inputs more accurately. I have updated code to cover all mentioned cases, please check

Answer (score 0):

Thought this sounded like an interesting one, so wanted to throw in my two cents.

One approach to this scenario, is to use a function to validate the users response. This helps keep the code a bit more tidy, and makes maintenance easier, than a monolithic approach.

Additionally, the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions) is a lovely little gem given to us in Python 3.8, whereby a value can be assigned, mid-expression and later reused. This technique is implemented in the `while` loop which waits to exit until a user's input (`resp`) is deemed 'valid' by the `_is_valid` function.

```
def _is_valid(resp):
    """Validate the user's input."""
    if resp.lower() == 'exit':
        return 'exit'
    try:
        resp = int(resp)
        if 0 <= resp <= 100:
            return resp
    except ValueError:
        pass
    print('  [ERROR]: An integer in the range [0, 100] is expected.')
    return False

def main():
    """Entry point and program controller."""
    while True:
        while not ( resp := _is_valid(input("\nEnter a grade (or type 'exit' to quit): ")) ):
            pass
        if resp == 'exit': 
            break
        if resp >= 80:
            print("You got an A")
        elif 70 <= resp < 80:
            print("You got a B")
        elif 60 <= resp < 70:
            print("You got a C")
        elif 50 <= resp < 60:
            print("You got a D")
        elif resp < 50:
            print("You got an F")

main()
```

---

**Sample output:**

```
Enter a grade (or type 'exit' to quit):  
  [ERROR]: An integer in the range [0, 100] is expected.

Enter a grade (or type 'exit' to quit):  bob
  [ERROR]: An integer in the range [0, 100] is expected.

Enter a grade (or type 'exit' to quit):  3.14159
  [ERROR]: An integer in the range [0, 100] is expected.

Enter a grade (or type 'exit' to quit):  -42
  [ERROR]: An integer in the range [0, 100] is expected.

Enter a grade (or type 'exit' to quit):  173
  [ERROR]: An integer in the range [0, 100] is expected.

Enter a grade (or type 'exit' to quit):  100
You got an A

Enter a grade (or type 'exit' to quit):  90
You got an A

Enter a grade (or type 'exit' to quit):  60
You got a C

Enter a grade (or type 'exit' to quit):  exit
```

---

**Requirements:**

- If an integer [0, 100] is entered, the value is scored (A-F).
- If 'exit' (in any case) is entered, the program exits.
- Any other value is considered invalid, and user should be warned that an integer is required and prompted again with 'Enter a grade: '.